# JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 dynamic css menubutton

Tags: java, css, oracle, javafx, scenebuilder

Ok guys I have downloaded `IssueTrackerLite` source code from oracle and have been messing the the `fxml` in `Scene Builder 2.0`.  I have added a MenuButton with the `fx:id` of cssTheme and what I want it to do is when the program is check a directory and load all of the css files in that dir into the list, then when you select one it will update the theme/css style on the fly.

Kind of vague I know but I am under pressure to learn this very quickly for a client with little to no experience in JavaFX.

IssueTrackerLite: [Download Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/IssueTrackingLite.zip)

Comment: you just use `scene.getStylesheets().remove(0);` and `scene.getStylesheets().add(0,"url");`.  Change the 0s to whatever you need.  The scene updates right away.

Comment: That's as far as I got, I'm just not sure how to make my Menu button populate with all the styles in the directory, then update based on which one is chosen.

Comment: So you want a files list of *.css in the menu?  You can't just use a file chooser?

Comment: I might be able to I will have to ask the client.  I think they want a drop down button with a list of available themes(which would reference css styles) and then you can just choose one to switch themes.

Comment: I posted a sample, but just a snip I added to my program.  It adds css files to a menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in Application start

```
    File userPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    for (String s : userPath.list())
        if (s.endsWith(".css")){
            MenuItem mi = new MenuItem(s);
            //using already made menu in my prog
            controller.mnuEdit.getItems().add(mi);
            mi.setOnAction((e)->{
                //always adding and removing from position 1
                //I already have a style sheet set at 0 
                scene.getStylesheets().remove(1);
                try {
                    scene.getStylesheets().add(1,new File(
                            System.getProperty("user.dir")+
                            System.getProperty("file.separator")+s)
                            .toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                }
            });
        }
```

Just in case you don't have a ref to controller, I load my fxml like this.

```
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("myprog/language/Base", Locale.getDefault()));
        rootScene = fxmlLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("Base.fxml").openStream());
        controller = (BaseController) fxmlLoader.getController();
    } catch (IOException ex) {log.severe(ex.getMessage());}
```